# PineScript - How to fire Alert only once? Trigger variable stops the alert

Tags: pine-script, alert, pine-script-v5

I have a condition on higher timeframe when the alert must be triggered and it works fine, but this condition may last for hours and I have the alert on a smaller timeframe, so I keep getting the same alert many many times in a row.

I created a boolean variable (trigger) to change it from True to False once the alert is triggered in order to make sure that I get the alert only once. This trigger will only reset back to True after the next condition happens.

It totally makes sense, right? At least for me :-)
However if I add this additional trigger condition it just stops firing alerts at all and I have no idea why it's happening.

Can someone please explain what am I doing wrong here?

```
var bool Trigger = true // adding the Trigger as true by default

if LongSignal and Trigger // when LongSignal happens and Trigger is still set to true
    alert("Long Signal", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
    Trigger := false // Switch Trigger to false
```

The code above is enough to make the alerts stop working, I guess no need to paste the code how I was going to switch the Trigger back, but anyway it would be like this:

```
if ExitLongSignal and not Trigger // when ExitLongSignal happens and Trigger is set to false
    alert("Exit Long Signal", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
    Trigger := true // Switch Trigger back to true
```

I really need help with this :-( I've seen some solutions with "barssince" but I didn't understand how and why that works and I first need to understand what's wrong with this straightforward method which I'm trying to apply. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
and ta.barssince(LongSignal)[1]
```

seems to stop multiple alerts and no Trigger variable is required at all

```
If LongSignal and ta.barssince(LongSignal)[1]
```

I hope I won't run into other issues with this when I start creating Exit LongSignal alerts...